# JSONpath Stopper

Tags: json, kettle, jsonpath, data-integration

There is a parent field called "price", but there is also a deeply-embedded child field also called "price" (first one is probably MSRP). How do I get JSONpath to only parse the parent ones?

```
{
 "name":"Toaster",
 "price":"19.99",
 "store":{
   "retailer":"Ants in My Eyes Johnson",
   "price":"9.99",
   "currency":"USD",
  }
 }
```

Using "$..price" yields:

```
"19.99"
"9.99"
```

I only want it to display

```
"19.99"
```

Not quite sure how.

Comment: If you are only interested in the parent node, you could store an array or list of the keys already seen.
If you encounter a child node whose key is already contained in the "seen" list, ignore it.

Comment: Why do you need to go through all the descendants? If you want just the root value, why don't you just use the direct path `$.price`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `..` in `$..price` means that you want to search the entire document.  Using a single `.` instead will only search directly under the given location.

Therefore to only search directly under the root and display

```
"19.99"
```

You should use the following JSON Path

```
$.price
```

You can see this working online using the json query tool here:
http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathtoplevel